# Vortex generated as a result of Newton's third law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, resonance, vortex

This books states this process as a result of Newton's third law. However I just can't find ways to graps how the "vortex" is generated, is it a fundamental law? (The question emerges on the 4th line).

[image]

Any guess/help would very appreciated, Thank you!

(and) = (e)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

What physical process is this claiming to describe?  And what is the book and who are the authors?

This does not resemble anything I've ever seen in physics; certainly not Newtonian Mechanics.  I think the source may be unreliable nonsense.

When two vectors add, e.g. two forces act on a point,  they are arranged tip to tail, and the total force is the new vector that points from Tail 1 to Tip 2.  In the case of equal and opposite vectors, they sum to zero.

[image: example]

Comment: Hello, the book is Coherence by Carlos Orozco.
Yeah... it's not common newtonian physics.